# Use PHP to prevent XSS attacks within an image

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, xss

After reading http://dsecrg.com/files/pub/pdf/XSS_in_images_evasion_bypass_(eng).pdf, it is clear that allowing image uploads from users opens you to XSS attacks.

I wasn't able to find any PHP examples of how to screen an uploaded image for XSS attacks.

I found one for **CodeIgniter**, which I am using. The function is `xss_clean($file, IS_IMAGE)`, but there is only 1 sentence of documentation for it, so I have no idea how it works and a comment in their forum said it had an unreasonably high rate of false positives, so it's not usable in production.

What do you recommend to prevent XSS attacks within an uploaded image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you keep the extension correct (and your users are diligent about updating their browser) image injection should not be possible.

For instance, if someone uploads `alert('xss');` as an image and you have `<img src='that-image.png'>`, it will be emitted as a png and the JavaScript won't execute (at least back to IE7).  What's important is that you rename the images appropriately.

If you have php > 5.3 and the `finfo` PECL extension, you can use it to get the mime type of the file and have a whitelist of types you will allow (png, jpg, gif I would imagine).  If you are on a Linux machine, `file` may help you with that as well.

Comment: I personally just emit all as application/octet-stream

Comment: Thanks Explosion, this is how I will handle it.

As stated in the article I linked to above:

"One can, of course, ignore this problem stating that it comes from the application flaw. However, a cyber‐crook can install and use PHP shell via a picture in the presence of local PHP include vulnerability and in that case, features of a browser will no longer be relevant. This fact confirms that if we are dealing with user's data, filtering is necessary in any case."

That scared me but my server is updated and after thinking about it ... I don't really care if IE 7 users get owned by a hacker.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter there's many way to prevent the XSS. You can enable it when getting the value like ->post('data', true). The second parameter is the XSS bool.

Also, don't use the HTML IMG tag. Use the CodeIgniter one that will clean, look and make it easier to display the image.

Just my two cents!

Comment: I'm not sure if that would actually filter the image (maybe just the filename?) unless you specifically use xss_clean($file, TRUE). See IS_IMAGE here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html

Comment: Yep, the `img()` function in the Codeigniter [HTML Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img) **does no security checks at all**, it merely constructs an `<img>` tag.  My preferred method is to get the MIME type of the image and only allow types you know to be safe…